# Python Flask webserver stop responding

Tags: python, flask

I am running a flask web server, it works fine during testing, but now freezes at least once per day. All I need to do is to restart it and it will work again. Is there a good way to monitor it and maybe I should just kill/restart it every time it fails. Do people actually kill their web server periodically to avoid this kind thing from happening?

Comment: Are you using flask web server in deployment?

Comment: To expand Bartosz' question: The default webserver that comes built in with flask is for development only - it's not suitable for production.  To deploy flask apps, you need a better WSGI server.  See the docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/

Comment: it is my flask web application. I basically start it and leave it running. I am not using anything else (ngix, apache).

Comment: What Daniel said. Don't use the dev server in production.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the default Flask webserver: Don't. It's intended for development ONLY.

As additional resource it's worth reading these two blog posts about deploying a Flask application:

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux-even-on-the-raspberry-pi
http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xviii-deployment-on-the-heroku-cloud

And for monitoring processes in your webserver, you could give Watchy a try:

http://redbrain.github.io/watchy/

Answer (score 3):

While the default web server might not be the best for production, it is probably not the root cause of the crashes.   I use it in a production environment on an internal network and it is very stable.  Before blaming the web server check to make sure your code can handle requests that that may collide with each other.   In my case I had lots of stability issues before I instituted locking on data base tables so that certain requests would be blocked until previous requests were done with updates.   Flask can't make sure your code is thread safe.  And changing the web server won't help if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to change worker_class from 'sync' to 'gevent', since I do some asynchronous tasks. Then no more hangs.